# Error while instantiating 'Queue'

Tags: java

I opened a class and I wrote:

```
private Queue<Player> players;
```

and then in the constructor:

```
this.players = new Queue<Players>();
```

but it says it's an error:

> cannot instantiate the type `Queue<Player>`

I created a class `Player` with constructor and everything and I also imported `Queue.`

What might be the problem?

Comment: `Queue` is an interface or abstract class

Comment: `Queue<E>` is interface, so it cannot be instantiated. You should create an instance of *concrete* class, for example `this.players = new LinkedList<>()`

Comment: Yes Queue is an interface use  ArrayDeque,PriorityQueue,etc

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using java.util.Queue, it's an interface. You need a concrete implementation of the Queue interface to create an instance of Queue.

You can choose one of the java.util.Queue implementations. For example,

```
Queue<String> myQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: You can use the diamond operator from Java 7 onward to do automatic generic type inference. (ie. `Queue<String> myQ = new LinkedList<>();`)